# Python Datetime : use strftime() with a timezone-aware date

Tags: python, datetime, utc

Suppose I have date `d` like this :

```
>>> d 
datetime(2009, 4, 19, 21, 12, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -7200))
```

As you can see, it is "timezone aware", there is an offset of 2 Hour, utctime is

```
>>> d.utctimetuple() 
time.struct_time(tm_year=2009, tm_mon=4, tm_mday=19, 
                 tm_hour=23, tm_min=12, tm_sec=0, 
                 tm_wday=6, tm_yday=109, tm_isdst=0)
```

So, real UTC date is 19th March 2009 **23**:12:00, right ?

Now I need to format my date in string, I use

```
>>> d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f') 
'2009-04-19 21:12:00.000000'
```

Which doesn't seems to take this offset into account. How to fix that ?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In addition to what @Slam has already answered:

If you want to output the UTC time without any offset, you can do

```
from datetime import timezone, datetime, timedelta
d = datetime(2009, 4, 19, 21, 12, tzinfo=timezone(timedelta(hours=-2)))
d.astimezone(timezone.utc).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

See [datetime.astimezone](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone) in the Python docs.

Comment: How can it be done in Python 2.7? no `timezone` module there

Comment: @itamar Katz please please don't use Python 2.7

Comment: @MichaelCurrie it's been more then 4 years, I'm not using 2.7 anymore...

Comment: Excellent!  However, my comment would have also applied in 2019 :D

Answer (score 22):

The reason is python actually formatting your datetime object, not some "UTC at this point of time"

To show timezone in formatting, use `%z` or `%Z`.

Look for [strf docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for details

Comment: Since by default `%z` seems to give the offset without colon (`:`), this might also be useful: https://gist.github.com/mattstibbs/a283f55a124d2de1b1d732daaac1f7f8

Comment: Yes, python still does not provide support for `%:z` formatting, but just to warn you on your gist: there's support for sub-minute TZs in python, so your code may break on exotic data

Answer (score 2):

This will convert your local time to UTC and print it:

```
import datetime, pytz
from dateutil.tz.tz import tzoffset

loc = datetime.datetime(2009, 4, 19, 21, 12, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -7200))

print(loc.astimezone(pytz.utc).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f') )
```

(http://pytz.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't import timezone module (and hadn't much time to know why)
so I set TZ environment variable which override the /etc/localtime information

```
>>> import os
>>> import datetime
>>> print  datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
2019-05-17 11:26
>>> os.environ["TZ"] = "UTC"
>>> print  datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
2019-05-17 09:26
```

Comment: ``timezone`` is for Python 3. Python 2.7 is EOL and you should upgrade to Python 3.8.

Comment: @wyz23x2  the appliance operating system was  so much locked that I simply had no other options.